# powershell can't click a button

Tags: powershell, button

i wanted to start my journey with powershell, but it seems I can't figure out why button on this site is not responding

https://s1.wcy.wat.edu.pl/ed/

(this is my uni site)

I want to be able to sign in via script.

I've been trying different variations like

`$submitButton = $ie.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("input") | 
Where-Object {$_.value -eq ' Zaloguj się '}
$submitButton.click()`

or

`$submitButton = $ie.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("input") | 
Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'submit'}
$submitButton.click()`

but i always get error.

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of $submitButton and what is the constructor for $submitButton.click() ? Run $submitButton.click to view the constructor

Comment: `+ $submitButton = $ie.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull` This is what i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way...

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate('https://s1.wcy.wat.edu.pl/ed') 

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}

$UserID = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT') | 
Where-Object {$($_.Name) -match 'userid'}
$UserId.value = 'UserID'

$UserPassword = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT') | 
Where-Object {$($_.Name) -match 'password'}
$UserPassword.value = 'password'

$Submit = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT') | 
Where-Object {$($_.Value) -match 'Zaloguj'}
$Submit.click()
```

Since scraping this, the INPUT was more reliable, since they all are INPUT tags.

```
$wcy = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://s1.wcy.wat.edu.pl/ed'
$wcy.Forms[0] | Format-List -Force
$wcy.Forms[0].Fields
$wcy.InputFields
```

I just tested this, so I know it works. Well, it did for me. Well, of course the login in failed due to invalid creds.  ***;-}***

You were not getting a match (that error message) with the -eq due to the string not being read as expected. Using match worked better.

Comment: Thanks you for an answer and explanation. Now it works.